# Want to search string in the array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I want to search this employee array which is consisted of objects and i should be able to search any text like if i pass ---> search_for_string_in_array ('aaron', employees) ; it should display me 'Value exists in array' or if its the way please help me..

```
//here is the employeee  array ...
  var employees =[{
                          name:"jacob",
                          age :23,
                          city:"virginia",
                          yoe :12,
                          image :'a.jpg'
                       },
                       {
                          name:"aaron",
                          age :21,
                          city:"virginia",
                          yoe :12,
                          image :'b.jpg'
                       },
                       {
                          name:"johnny",
                          age :50,
                          city:"texas",
                          yoe :12,
                          image :'c.jpg'
                       },
                       {
                          name:"jacob",
                          age :12,
                          city:"virginia",
                          yoe :12,
                          image :'a.jpg'
                       }];
```

here is the function which performs searching functionality inside an array.

```
    function search_for_string_in_array(search_for_string, employees) 
            {
                for (var i=0; i < employees.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (employees[i].match(search_for_string))
                    { 
                        return 'Value exists in array';
                    }
                }
               return 'Value does NOT exist in array';
            }
```

Simply pass the value to search for and the array to the function and it will tell you whether the string exists as a part of an array value or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the Array, you should probably just loop through it and test each value. If you don’t know the structure, you can stringify the array into JSON and regexp it (although it won’t be as safe):

```
function search_for_string_in_array(str, arr) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(arr);
    return new RegExp(':\"'+str+'\"','g').test(json);
}
```

Comment: hey david thnx ....but its searching for values only ,it does give result for keys  like if object has a property --> name :"jacob" ,it return true when u pass it ,but when u pass "name" it returns false

Comment: Just remove the colon if you want to search keys too `'\"'+str+'\"'`

Answer (score 0):

just replace the line

```
if (employees[i].match(search_for_string))
```

with this:

```
if (employees[i].name.match(search_for_string))
```

Comment: ...assuming 'name' is the only key you are looking for.

Comment: You right, So he can add another parameter - array which holds all the keys he wants to look on. I really did not understand his question - I thought he is just asking on how objects works...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function search(text) {
    text += '';
    var i, obj;
    var array = [];
    for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        var obj = employees[i];
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (('' + obj[key]).indexOf(text) >= 0
                        || ('' + key).indexOf(text) >= 0) {
                    array.push(obj);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return array.length > 0;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AL9yw/2/) [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AL9yw/3/)

Comment: Thnx Arun but its jst giving me the "values" of an object ,not giving "key" suppose we have { name :"jacob" },it returns true when u pass it jacob ,but when u pass "name" it returns false

Comment: @user1948425 when you pass `name` what should it return

Comment: it should return true because it exits in object

Comment: @user1948425 so in the previous case both `jacob` and `name` should return true

Comment: yeah exactly ...i m getting this using function     search_for_string_in_array(str, arr) {
          var json = JSON.stringify(arr);
          return new RegExp('\"'+str+'\"' ,'g').test(json);
      } 
 but it contains regex ,i want without it'

Comment: @user1948425 you want to do it without using regex

Comment: @ Arun u seem a great programmer the way u write a  program is awesome i also want to do gud programming n m learning n wanna learn it upto its core any advice or links for practice u want to share i will b vry grateful to u ..

Comment: oh thnx few days before i asked u a question n u answerd me the above function that was cool but not getting the line where we r matching the value that line is ...if (('' + obj[key]).indexOf(text) >= 0 || ('' + key).indexOf(text) >= 0)  how its xactly working plz explain it as m new to js